# Java EE Security - personal user's data visible only for him

Tags: security, java-ee-6

I am just learning Java EE and have encountered on a problem connected with security. Java EE has realms,users,roles and that is all. If current user has the required role to be authorized - he is, anotherwise he fails. My problem is - how to make java ee security to obey such a security constraint - personal user's data is visible only for him. Theoretically, I could make for every user his "role" and programmatically  check if user has role of the user owning that data. It seems for me to be very inconvenient solution (many, many roles). Is Java EE Security capable to deal with such a security constraint as in title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Java EE's standard security model does not address this kind of per-user security directly.

Rather, you will need to manually. Whenever you handle a request for sensitive data, you need to write code that checks the user's identity and allows or refuses the request. You can find the user's identity via [`EJBContext::getCallerPrincipal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html#getCallerPrincipal%28%29), [`HttpServletRequest::getUserPrincipal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29), or using [JAAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service) if you have a working JAAS context.

Yes, this is incredibly awkward and painful. No, there is really nothing in Java EE that will make this easier. There may well be third-party libraries that help, but i'm afraid i don't know of any.